# Rails 3 ActionMailer: normal and inline attachments in the same email?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I'd like to create an html email with a normal attachement (a pdf file), and an inline attachment (an image) as well. These two attachment types work perfectly individually, but don't seem to live well together: the normal attachement disappears (at least in Outlook) as soon as there is an inline attachment.

Is it a bad thing to mix attachment types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is a bad idea to mix attachment types as this is a documented issue currently with Action Mailer. Refer to https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2686 for more details.